# Grep regex not working with square brackets

Tags: regex, bash, grep, quoting

So I was trying to write a regex in grep to match square brackets, i.e `[ad]` should match `[` and `]`. But I was getting different results on using capturing groups and character classes. Also the result is different on putting `'` in the beginning and end of regex string.

So these are the different result that I am getting.

Using capturing groups works fine

```
echo "[ad]" | grep -E '(\[|\])'
[ad]
```

Using capturing groups without `'` gives syntax error

```
echo "[ad]" | grep -E (\[|\])
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

using character class with `[` followed by `]` gives no output

```
echo "[ad]" | grep -E [\[\]]
```

Using character class with `]` followed by `[` works correctly

```
echo "[ad]" | grep -E [\]\[]
[ad]
```

Using character class with `]` followed by `[` and using `'` does not work

```
echo "[ad]" | grep -E '[\]\[]'
```

It'd be great if someone could explain the difference between them.

Comment: Half of those are just about how the shell parses command line arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should know about:

#### BRE ( = Basic Regular  Expression )

#### ERE ( = Extended Regular Expression )

---

**BRE** metacharacters require a backslash to give them their special meaning and `grep` is based on

The **ERE** flavor standardizes a flavor similar to the one used by the UNIX `egrep` command.

---

Pay attention to `-E` and `-G`

```
grep --help
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.
PATTERN is, by default, a basic regular expression (BRE).
Example: grep -i 'hello world' menu.h main.c

Regexp selection and interpretation:
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
  -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings
  -G, --basic-regexp        PATTERN is a basic regular expression (BRE)
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  ...
  ...
```

#### [`POSIX Basic Regular Expressions`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

#### [`POSIX Extended Regular Expressions`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

#### [`POSIX Bracket Expressions`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

---

And you should also know about [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), since some of your input is related to bash interpreter not `grep` or anything else

```
echo "[ad]" | grep -E (\[|\])
```

Here [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) assumes you try to use `()` something like:

```
echo $(( 10 * 10 ))
```

and by using single quote `'` you tell the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) that you do not want it treats as a special operator for it. So

```
echo "[ad]" | grep -E '(\[|\])'
```

is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, always quote Regex pattern to prevent shell interpretation beforehand:

```
$ echo "[ad]" | grep -E '(\[|\])'
[ad]
```

Secondly, within `[]` surrounded by quotes, you don't need to escape the `[]` inside, just write them as is within the outer `[]`:

```
$ echo "[ad]" | grep -E '[][]'
[ad]
```

Comment: Why `'[][]'` is not treated as two character classes?

Comment: @PrashantGupta because it's defined not to be so. Several characters have different meanings based on their relative location in a bracket expression, including `]`, `^`, and `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you provided such a simple example on purpose (after all, it is minimal), but in case all you really want is to check for existence of square brackets (**a fixed string, not regex pattern**), you can use `grep` with `-F`/`--fixed-strings` and multiple `-e` options:

```
$ echo "[ad]" | grep -F -e '[' -e ']'
[ad]
```

Or, a little bit shorter with `fgrep`:

```
$ echo "[ad]" | fgrep -e '[' -e ']'
[ad]
```

Or, even:

```
$ echo "[ad]" | fgrep -e[ -e]
[ad]
```